# replace hours in a datetime type python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime type mydate in `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` format.
I want to replace the hours
I did this using `mydate.replace()` method
Now I want to comapre it with another specific date -> myNEWdate whose format is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` :

```
    newdate = mydate.replace(hour = islot)
    print newdate
    appointmentDict[mydate]['time_start'] = datetime.strptime(str(newdate),"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The date is printed as `2015-06-26 08:00:00`
and I get the error

```
ValueError: time data '2015-06-26 08:00:00' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
```

What should I do to resolve this

Comment: Why do you convert the `datetime` object into string and back to `datetime` object?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to convert `newdate` to string, then back to `datetime`. You may assign the value directly. Just do `appointmentDict[mydate]['time_start'] = newdate` which is already a `datetime`. It will also allow you to compare properly, as `datetime` objects rather than as strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the correct format

```
datetime.strptime(str(newdate),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

To solve the exception. Although converting from datetime 2 string and backwards doesn't make much sense, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Which error? If i try it in my idle i get a datetime from the given string.

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava: same error? I doubt it... @Iwan1993's answer is correct, as you can execute `datetime.strptime('2015-06-26 08:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` without getting any `ValueError`. You shouldn't downvote. It fixes the problem you are complaining about. If it still doesn't work, then you have multiple errors in your code.

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava: also, read the comments bellow your question; it makes no sense to do that `datetime` to `str` conversion.

Comment: @Peque: no hard feelings...just that this solution doesnt work for me

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava: I really doubt you can't execute `datetime.strptime('2015-06-26 08:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` (copy and paste that line). If so, which error are you getting?